# How to limit AWS Lambda instances without reserve concurrencies?

Tags: concurrency, aws-lambda

After reading [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html#configuration-concurrency-reserved) is still can not figure out. IF there is a way to limit AWS lambda without reserving concurrencies. IS it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Why doesn't the reserved concurrency work for you? Tell us your use case.

Comment: Non mission critical lambda. I wish to limit it on one hand. But not reserving instances on thew other hand

Comment: Which trigger do you use in your lambda ? Kinesis, SQS, ApiGateway etc ?

Comment: CloudWatch Logs